Are allocatable derived type components just pointers for GNU compiler?
Consider the following minimal example:
program prog
    type node
        integer::val
        type(node),allocatable::next
    end type
    type(node)::a,b
    allocate(a%next)
    a%val=1
    a%next%val=2
    print*,a%val,a%next%val
    b=a
    b%val=3
    b%next%val=4
    print*,a%val,a%next%val
    deallocate(b%next)
    print*,a%val,a%next%val
end

The output of the code compiled with the GNU (gfortran-13.1.0) compiler is as follows:
           1           2
           1           4
           1           0

While the output of the code compiled with the Intel (ifx-2024.1.0) or NAG (nagfor-7.1) compiler is different:
           1           2
           1           2
           1           2

It seems like gfortran treats allocatable derived type components somewhat as pointers: after assignment b=a, the memory addresses of a%next and b%next are the same, and you can change a%next%val by changing b%next%val. However, deallocation of b%next will not deallocate a%next and will only change its content.
In contrast to this behavior, the Intel and NAG compilers perform a deep copy in the assignment b=a allocating new memory for elements of b.
As this results are compiler-dependent, is it an undefined behavior (i.e., undefined by the Fortran standard)? Or is the GNU compiler wrong?

The GCC results presented are wrong. How much justification for that are you after?

@francescalus I think, I understand, why the GCC results are wrong. I just wanted to make sure, if there is some undefined behavior that I'm not aware of. I will report this bug to the GCC Bugzilla.

@francescalus you can answer this question, if you'd like. I will accept it as the solution.

I did draft an answer, but it turned out a bit long and rambling. Let me see what I can do.
